# I need to group my Data in View Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
{
"id": "1",
"item_quantity": "3",
"item_id": "3",
"item_color": "White",
},
{
"id": "2",
"item_quantity": "3",
"item_id": "3",
"item_color": "Black",
},

{
"id": "3",
"item_quantity": "3",
"item_id": "4",
"item_color": "White",
},
```

Hi guys my output in Laravel using foreach is this,
ItemId:3 ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:White 
ItemId:3 ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:Black
ItemId:4 ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:White

But what I need is to combine those Item with the same ID like this,
ItemID:3 ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:White/ ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:Black
ItemId:4 ItemQuantity:3 ItemColor:White

BTW I use Table in my View, and Foreach to display may Data.

Thank you guys.. this is Laravel 4.2

Comment: Try to be more clear on what you are asking. Is this a stock table that is related to a item table?

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($items as $item1)
  <tr>{{$item1->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$item1->item_quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{$item1->item_color}}</td>
     @foreach($items as $item2)
       @if($item1->item_id == $item2->item_id)
          <td>{{$item2->item_quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{$item2->item_color}}</td>
       @endif
    @endforeach
   </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your input objet but something like this:

```
function group_items($items){
    $groupedOutput = array();
    for each($items as $item){
        $key = 'id_'.$item;
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $groupedOutput)){
            $groupedOutput[$key] = array();
        }
        $groupedOutput[$key][] = $item;
    }
    return $groupedOutput;
}

function print_items($groupedOutput){
    for each($groupedOutput as $items){
        for each($items as $item){
            $itemId = $item['item_id'];
            $itemQuantity = $item['item_quantity'];
            $itemColor = $item['item_color'];
            echo "ItemID:$itemId ItemQuantity:$itemQuantity ItemColor:$itemColor/ ";
        }
    }
}


//To group output
$groupedOutput = group_items($items);

//To print grouped output
print_items($groupedOutput);
// OR
var_dump(json_encode($groupedOutput));
```